# Scaling the image -- Quality check

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage

Does scaling the image using: `image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];` reduces the image quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean something like compression artefacts then no, cause those are added when it comes to saving to disc in a specific format like JPG.

There is also a yes, because you double the dimensions of the image which will interpolate the pixels that never have been there, this will always look blurry starting at a certain point.